# Method naming in Map class: keySet(), entrySet() and values()

Tags: java

I've been thinking about the naming of three methods in the famous Map class. To get all keys in the map we use keySet(), for entries there is entrySet() and for values the values() method is used.

What I find a bit peculiar is that the first two methods includes the returned type (set) in the name. Wouldn't it be nicer to exclude it? That would mean that the method names would be harmonized and it would look quite nice (imho!):

```
keys()
entries()
values()
```

The other alternative would be to suffix the values() method:

```
keySet()
entrySet()
valueCollection()
```

To me this doesn't look as good and makes the code ugly.

This is a philosophical question as changing the method naming would break the backward compatibility.

Any thoughts on the topic?

Comment: Thoughts - this is very opinion based and exactly the type of question that doesn't suit this site. I'm afraid I've voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

The main intention of having the `Set` is to signify that the returned collection would have the characteristics of `Set` (i.e) it will not contain any duplicates.

And since `values()` like the others, returns a `Collection`(mind you, `keySet` and `entrySet` also return a collection, but a specific one, `Set`), it would quite trivial to include the `collection` word in the method name.

Comment: @NarendraPathai - Yeah! Saw that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping method names as `keySet` or `entrySet` shows your intent that you are returning a `Set` and committing to the characteristics of `Set` namely no duplicates.

On keeping names as `keys` or `entries` you should return a `Collection` or `Iterable` so that shows the intent that the implementation has not committed to any particular type of Collection and that may change in future.